# Small regex nfa matching while possibly larger matches are running

Tags: c, regex, io, virtual-machine, nfa

I'm creating my own lexical analyzer generator, similar to (f)lex. My plan was to make a tool like grep and go from there. Right now I've followed the articles by Russ Cox on creating an analyzer as a virtual machine: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp2.html

The issue I've run into is keeping track of small matches while a larger match is running. An example where this could happen is ".*d|ab" on the input string "abcabcabcabcabcabcd".

Currently, I have an NFA running which is practically the same as the one Cox made. It uses thompsons algorithm to compute dfa sets on the fly from the nfa. The threads are stored in a sparse set. (Preston Briggs and Linda Torczon's 1993 paper, “An Efficient Representation for Sparse Sets,”)

Threads that appear earlier in this list have larger importance and eliminate later threads upon accepting.

My current implementation can find a word matching a regex, but cannot continously keep on matching. To show what currently happens, lets look at the above example regex and string.

The first step makes three threads. Two for the left side of the union, one for the right side. Only the threads taking the wildcard and 'a' advance into the next list.

Step two advances again the wildcard and the thread taking a 'b' this time. It also adds new thread to try and match from this character as starting point.

Step three advances the wildcard and puts the thread running "ab" into an accepting state. Now the newer (less priority) threads are removed and a new threads are added to start matching from this character.

This is where the problem starts: The nfa cannot output a match on "ab" yet. It should wait for ".*d" to finish. This means that for a large input file, a lot of matches should be buffered until the ".*d" terminates (which is at the last character to get the potential largest match)

Thus, the actual question is: What is an efficient way to store these matches or is there another way to not have to potentially buffer the whole input file?

As a side note on the code: The code is so similar to the article of Cox that any questions related to how the code functions can be viewed in the article. Also, I've downloaded and tested the code of Cox and it had the same issue as described above.

What I hope to get with the solution to this question is to get my nfa implementation to match text in the exact same way grep or lex would: with the longest leftmost matches.

As requested, code fragments:

VM opcodes representing ".*d|ab":

```
0 SPLIT 2, 5
1 ANY
2 SPLIT 1, 3
3 CHAR 'd'
4 JMP 7
5 CHAR 'a'
6 CHAR 'b'
7 ACCEPT
```

CHAR asserts input character to match first operand.

SPLIT creates two new threads starting at the first and second operand.

ANY matches any input character.

JMP sets the program counter to the first operand.

ACCEPT puts the current thread in an accepting state.

An add function to recursively go through opcodes until reaching an CHAR or ACCEPT opcode then adding these to the next threadlist.

```
static void recursive_add(struct NFA *nfa, struct Thread *thread)
{
    switch(nfa->code[thread->pc])
    {
        case OPCODE_JMP:
            printf("    |   jmp\n");
            thread->pc = nfa->code[thread->pc + 1];
            recursive_add(nfa, thread);
            break;

        case OPCODE_SPLIT:
        {
            uint16_t pc = thread->pc;
            printf("    |   split: %d op1: %d op2: %d\n", thread->pc, nfa->code[thread->pc + 1], nfa->code[thread->pc + 2]);
            thread->pc = nfa->code[thread->pc + 1];
            recursive_add(nfa, thread);
            thread->pc = nfa->code[pc + 2];
            recursive_add(nfa, thread);
            break;
        }

        case OPCODE_CHAR:   case OPCODE_ACCEPT:
            printf("    |   char/accept %d\n", thread->pc);
            add_sparseset(nfa->nthreads, thread);
            return;

        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected opcode %x at program counter %d\n", nfa->code[thread->pc],  thread->pc);
            exit(1);
    }
}
```

And the main loop, currently a bit messy but this should give a better idea of what the code does.

```
void execute_nfa(struct NFA *nfa)
{
    struct Thread thread;
    struct SparseSet *swap;
    char c;
    for(;;)
    {
        c = getchar();
        printf("Input char %c\n", c);

        //add new starting thread for every character
        thread.pc = 0;
        recursive_add(nfa, &thread);

        clear_sparseset(nfa->cthreads);
        swap = nfa->cthreads;
        nfa->cthreads = nfa->nthreads;
        nfa->nthreads = swap;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nfa->cthreads->size; i++)
        {
            thread = *(((struct Thread *)nfa->cthreads->dense) + i);
            printf("    thread pc: %d\n", thread.pc);
            switch(nfa->code[thread.pc])
            {
                case OPCODE_CHAR:
                    if(nfa->code[thread.pc + 1] == c)
                    {
                        printf("    Add to next\n");
                        thread.pc += 2;
                        recursive_add(nfa, &thread);
                    }
                    break;

                case OPCODE_ACCEPT:
                    printf("    accept (still need to do shit)\n");
                    break;

                default:
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected opcode %x at program counter %d\n", nfa->code[thread.pc],  thread.pc);
                    exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything here we can help you with unless you have some concrete code you're working on that we can fix.